# GTK How to rearrange items in a tree/list via drag and drop

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I am trying to rearrange items in a single GTK TreeView with a ListStore model. How can I do this?

Will I need to use the same method as dragging and dropping items from one list to another, or is there a special way of doing this for a single list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's method in GtkTreeView for that [GtkTreeView::gtk_tree_view_set_reorderable](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-reorderable)

Since  it seems your using mono, I don't know if the bindgins for mono allow that, but there's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was already setting Reorderable to true, however when calling another GTK# method later (SetDragDataSource or something to that effect), it was setting Reorderable to false. This is a ridiculous side effect, as setting Reorderable to true AFTER that call makes everything work as intended.